# mapping configs in application yml file to enum types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, properties

```
#Reports
reports:
    PnLReport:
        reportId: 10
        path: \\\\pathto\\PnLreport\\

    BalanceSheetReport:
            reportId: 11
            path: \\\\pathto\\balancesheet\\    

schedule-10:
    description: Deliver pnl reports
    report: 10
    format: PDF, XLS
```

I have the above properties defined in a`application.yml` file in my `Spring Boot` application.

1. How can I map the `repordId` and `path` properties to a `enum` for example for each of the reports types. For example:

   ```
   public enum ReportType{
   PNL(...)
   BALANCE(...);

   private final String reportId;
   private final String path;

   private ReportType(String reportId, String path) {
       this.identifier = identifier;
   }
   ```
2. Next, I would like map between `report: 10` under the `schedule-10` property to the `reportId` to derive the path in a `FileService` class for example so that I can look if the files exist in the path. How can I do this mapping?
3. This is the only way I can think of for my requirement, is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would recommend using an enumeration for this since what you're looking for is more like a configurable property instance. Maybe consider using a simple class instead and read two instances of it?

```
public class ReportType {

    private Integer reportId;

    private String path;

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void getReportId() {
        return reportId;
    }

    public Integer setReportId(Integer reportId) {
        this.reportId = reportId;
    }
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "reports")
public class ReportTypes {
    public ReportType PlnReport;
    public ReportType BalanceSheetReport;
}
```